# can send rest request to flush Redis database?

Tags: rest, redis

I'm using Redis server for caching data. I want to know how I can connect to Redis using rest request and flush database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, redis has its own protocol and networking layer, which is *not* RESTful. You'll need to talk to it in its own protocol and issue the FLUSHDB command.

Comment: what is its own protocol? i want to can flush it from an angularjs or java project. can i do this?

Comment: yes, you will need a redis client. for Java try Jedis, for JS try ioredis.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: Exposing redis to client-side like that feels... unsafe at best. :)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer ioredis is for node.js? i dont know how i can use it in angularjs.

Comment: You can't call redis from the browser, if that's what you are asking.